# How can I ssh directly to a particular directory?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ssh

I often have to login to one of several servers and go to one of several directories on those machines.  Currently I do something of this sort:

```
localhost ~]$ ssh somehost

Welcome to somehost!

somehost ~]$ cd /some/directory/somewhere/named/Foo
somehost Foo]$
```

I have scripts that can determine which host and which directory I need to get into but I cannot figure out a way to do this:

```
localhost ~]$ go_to_dir Foo

Welcome to somehost!

somehost Foo]$
```

Is there an easy, clever or any way to do this?

Answer (score 566, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
ssh -t xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "cd /directory_wanted ; bash --login"
```

This way, you will get a login shell right on the directory_wanted.

---

Explanation

> `-t` Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.
>
> Multiple `-t` options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

- If you don't use `-t` then no prompt will appear.
- If you don't add `; bash` then the connection will get closed and return control to your local machine
- If you don't add `bash --login` then it will not use your configs because it's not a login shell

Comment: Executing the shell at the end was the final piece of the puzzle.  Thank you.

Comment: in my case -t the missing part

Comment: When using this approach the .bash_profile is not read, anyone knows why?

Comment: @filipenf that's because when you launch bash "manualy" only .bashrc is loaded.

Comment: I had to do this:  `ssh -t xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "cd /directory_wanted && exec \$SHELL"`

Comment: `"cd /directory_wanted && bash"` is better in case when `/directory_wanted` does not exist.

Comment: You'll usually want a login shell: `ssh -t example.com "cd /foo/bar; exec \$SHELL -l"`

Comment: Just wanted to link [change directory automatically on ssh login - Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/a/215051); and from there paste this command ( which is a version of the one by @christianbundy ): `ssh server -t "cd /my/remote/directory; bash --login"`

Comment: for me, ssh -t xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "cd /directory_wanted && $SHELL" works fine

Comment: When I do this I end up without a prompt.  Bash still works fine but I like a prompt that shows the working directory.  I'm SSHing in from zsh.  Login shell doesn't help

Comment: Careful @Pejvan - you're trying to use the _local_ value of `$SHELL` on the _remote_ machine there!

Comment: If you have the host specified in .ssh/config then just `ssh [your host] -t "cd [your directory]; bash"`

Comment: where should `.ssh` folder located under `/directory_wanted ` ?

Comment: It is important to note that by the time the commands execute, `.bashrc` has not initialized yet, so many of your variables or presets might not be ready at this time

Answer (score 86):

You could add

```
cd /some/directory/somewhere/named/Foo
```

to your `.bashrc` file (or `.profile` or whatever you call it) at the other host. That way, no matter what you do or where you `ssh` from, whenever you log onto that server, it will `cd` to the proper directory for you, and all you have to do is use `ssh` like normal.

Of curse, rogeriopvl's solution works too, but it's a tad bit more verbose, and you have to remember to do it every time (unless you make an alias) so it seems a bit less "fun".

Comment: +1, this looks  more suitable if you  need constant directory instead of making ssh command longer remembering everytime to which directory you are going to move when you  connect to X machine

Comment: Not proper when changing flexibly

Answer (score 76):

My preferred approach is using the SSH config file (described below), but there are a few possible solutions depending on your usages.

## Command Line Arguments

I think the best answer for this approach is christianbundy's reply to the accepted answer:

```
ssh -t example.com "cd /foo/bar; exec \$SHELL -l"
```

Using double quotes will allow you to use variables from your local machine, unless they are escaped (as `$SHELL` is here). Alternatively, you can use single quotes, and all of the variables you use will be the ones from the target machine:

```
ssh -t example.com 'cd /foo/bar; exec $SHELL -l'
```

## Bash Function

You can simplify the command by wrapping it in a bash function. Let's say you just want to type this:

```
sshcd example.com /foo/bar
```

You can make this work by adding this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
sshcd () { ssh -t "$1" "cd \"$2\"; exec \$SHELL -l"; }
```

If you are using a variable that exists on the remote machine for the directory, be sure to escape it or put it in single quotes. For example, this will cd to the directory that is stored in the `JBOSS_HOME` variable on the remote machine:

```
sshcd example.com \$JBOSS_HOME
```

## SSH Config File

If you'd like to see this behavior all the time for specific (or any) hosts with the normal ssh command without having to use extra command line arguments, you can set the `RequestTTY` and `RemoteCommand` options in your ssh config file.

For example, I'd like to type only this command:

```
ssh qaapps18
```

but want it to always behave like this command:

```
ssh -t qaapps18 'cd $JBOSS_HOME; exec $SHELL'
```

So I added this to my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *apps*
    RequestTTY yes
    RemoteCommand cd $JBOSS_HOME; exec $SHELL
```

Now this rule applies to any host with "apps" in its hostname.

For more information, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html

Comment: `RequestTTY` combined with `RemoteCommand` was exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: this works better if you has a different shell like zsh

Comment: ```zsh:1: command not found: gs``` 
Does anyone have any idea reagarding to how I could make the shell that I am starting through ssh aware of the aliases on the remote machine? I tried using `source ~/.zshrc` as my first command in the double-quoted string that we pass to `ssh -t` (ie: `ssh -t my-remote.com "source ~/.zshrc; g; gs; exec $SHELL -l"`) but to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: I also tried this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425319/how-do-i-execute-a-remote-alias-over-an-ssh but it does not work for `zsh`

Answer (score 24):

I've created a tool to SSH and CD into a server consecutively – aptly named [sshcd](https://github.com/christianbundy/sshcd). For the example you've given, you'd simply use:

```
sshcd somehost:/some/directory/somewhere/named/Foo
```

Let me know if you have any questions or problems!

Comment: Would be cool if you could define a new config in ~/.ssh/config and read it from there ;)

Answer (score 20):

Based on additions to @rogeriopvl's answer, I suggest the following:

```
ssh -t xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "cd /directory_wanted && bash"
```

Chaining commands by `&&` will make the next command run only when the previous one was successful (as opposed to using `;`, which executes commands sequentially). This is particularly useful when needing to `cd` to a directory performing the command.

Imagine doing the following:

```
/home/me$ cd /usr/share/teminal; rm -R *
```

The directory `teminal` doesn't exist, which causes you to stay in the home directory and remove all the files in there with the following command.

If you use `&&`:

```
/home/me$ cd /usr/share/teminal && rm -R *
```

The command will fail after not finding the directory.

Comment: Used single quotes and not double quotes with a command without && once and it bit me in the butt, bad... learned my lesson.

Comment: After trying several solutions, it was this one which worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I use the environment variable CDPATH

Comment: Useful only if I was interested in one directory per machine.  I need a way to pass information to the remote machine.  Roger's solution does just that.

Comment: @Eddy can you give an example of this please?

Answer (score 4):

In my very specific case, I just wanted to execute a command in a remote host, inside a specific directory from a Jenkins slave machine:

```
ssh myuser@mydomain
cd /home/myuser/somedir 
./commandThatMustBeRunInside_somedir
exit
```

But my machine couldn't perform the ssh (it couldn't allocate a pseudo-tty I suppose) and kept me giving the following error:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal
```

I could get around this issue passing "cd to dir + my command" as a parameter of the ssh command (to not have to allocate a Pseudo-terminal) and by passing the option -T to explicitly tell to the ssh command that I didn't need pseudo-terminal allocation.

```
ssh -T myuser@mydomain "cd /home/myuser/somedir; ./commandThatMustBeRunInside_somedir"
```

Answer (score 4):

My answer may differ from what you really want, but I write here as may be useful for some people. In my solution you have to enter into the directory once and then every new ssh session goes to the same dir (after the first logout).

**How to ssh to the same directory you have been in your last login.**
(I assume you use bash on the remote node.)

Add this line to your ~/.bash_logout on the **remote node**(!):

```
echo $PWD > ~/.bash_lastpwd
```

and these lines to the ~/.bashrc file (still on the **remote node**!)

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_lastpwd ]; then
    cd $(cat ~/.bash_lastpwd)
fi
```

This way you save your current path on every logout and `.bashrc` put you into that directory after login.

ps: You can tweak it further like using the `SSH_CLIENT` variable to decide to go into that directory or not, so you can differentiate between local logins and ssh or even between different ssh clients.

Comment: This is great if you want to restore the state from your last session so it's like you have one continuous session that you log in and out of. But I think your second sentence is misleading, "enter into the directory once and then every new ssh session goes to the same dir (after the first logout)." It won't always visit the same directory from the first logout. It will visit whatever directory you were in at the last logout, which may change often.

Comment: It's not only useful if you have one continuous session. It works many sessions as well, but indeed it works the best if wish to work all your session in the same dir. Suggest a change for that sentence. I don't know how to write it short and clean.

Answer (score 3):

going one step further with the `-t` idea.  I keep a set of scripts calling the one below to go to specific places in my frequently visited hosts.  I keep them all in `~/bin` and keep that directory in my path.

```
#!/bin/bash

# does ssh session switching to particular directory
# $1, hostname from config file 
# $2, directory to move to after login
# can save this as say 'con' then
# make another script calling this one, e.g.
# con myhost repos/i2c

ssh -t $1 "cd $2; exec \$SHELL --login"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of going to directly after logging in is create "Alias".  When you login into your system just type that alias and you will be in that directory.

Example : Alias = myfolder '/var/www/Folder'

After you log in to your system type that alias (this works from any part of the system)
this command if not in bashrc will work for current session.  So you can also add this alias to bashrc to use that in future

$ myfolder => takes you to that folder

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered ages ago but I found the question while trying to incorporate an ssh login in a bash script and once logged in run a few commands and log back out and continue with the bash script. The simplest way I found which hasnt been mentioned elsewhere because it is so trivial is to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p "password" ssh user@server 'cd /path/to/dir;somecommand;someothercommand;exit;'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Connect With User

In case if you don't know this, you can use this to connect by specifying both user and host

```
ssh -t <user>@<Host domain / IP> "cd /path/to/directory; bash --login"
```

Example: `ssh -t admin@test.com "cd public_html; bash --login"`

You can also append the commands to be executed on every login by appending it in the double quotes with a `;` before each command

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the suggested solution (of @rogeriopvl) doesn't work when you use multiple hops, so I found another one.
On remote machine add into `~/.bashrc` the following:

```
[ "x$CDTO" != "x" ] && cd $CDTO
```

This allows you to specify the desired target directory on command line in this way:

```
ssh -t host1 ssh -t host2 "CDTO=/desired_directory exec bash --login"
```

Sure, this way can be used for a single hop too.

This solution can be combined with the usefull tip of @redseven for greater flexibilty (if no $CDTO, go to saved directory, if exists).

Answer (score -2):

SSH itself provides a means of communication, it does not know anything about directories. Since you can specify which remote command to execute (this is - by default - your shell), I'd start there.

Comment: This is a partial answer, not a solution.

Answer (score -7):

simply modify your home with the command: 
`usermod -d /newhome username`

Comment: Not advised.  Changing your home directory will probably cause other things to break.