# Can I ssh somewhere, run some commands, and then leave myself a prompt?

Tags: shell, ssh

I find myself needing to log into various servers, set environment variables, and then work interactively.

e.g.

```
$ ssh anvil
jla@anvil$ export V=hello
jla@anvil$ export W=world
jla@anvil$ echo $V $W
hello world
```

How can I combine the first few commands, and then leave myself at a prompt?

Something like:

```
$ ssh anvil --on-login 'export V=hello; export W=world;'
jla@anvil$ echo $V $W
hello world
```

Obviously this is a model problem. What I am really asking is 'how do I ssh to a different machine, run some commands, and then continue as if I'd run them by hand?'

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing is:

```
$ ssh -t host 'cmd1; cmd2; sh -i'
```

If you want to set variables, do:

```
$ ssh -t host 'cmd1; cmd2; FOO=hello sh -i'
```

Note that this is a terrible hack, and you would be much better off putting your desired initial commands in a script and doing:

```
$ scp setup host:~
$ ssh host
host$ . setup
```

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I'd like, but it doesn't work quite the same. It says things like 'no job control', and man pages don't use a pager.

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden Try adding -t

Comment: William, why do you say this is a terrible hack. It seems to work like a charm. Is there something unexpected waiting to bite me? What's the -i for?

Comment: @John It was a terrible hack before I added -t in an edit.  With -t, it does seem to work well.

Comment: @John The -i tells the shell to be interactive

Comment: If you change `sh -i` to `'$SHELL'` this will run the same shell interpreter that is configured on the remote account.

Comment: Oh, and you may wish to use `-l` instead of `-i`. (with both `$SHELL` and `sh`)

Comment: The expect script from jcollado works better. Since you're the accepted answer, you should consider updated your answer to recommend his answer instead.

Answer (score 18):

You could also use the following [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh $argv
send "export V=hello\n"
send "export W=world\n"
send "echo \$V \$W\n"
interact
```

Comment: This is super. I would rather have had something that could fit on a command line (and so appear in history, notes, etc). But I can make this work for what I want. Thanks!

Comment: This wont work unless you have ssh keys setup for identity (private key) public key authentication. Otherwise ssh will prompt you for login credentials and you'd have to add them to your expect script, which can be a security issue since your saving your password in a file. Using expect is an interesting option tho. I can't use it because we have RSA token authentication - which means my password is a new random number generated every 30sec.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out this is answered by this question:

[How can I ssh directly to a particular directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626533/how-can-i-ssh-directly-to-a-particular-directory)

to ssh:

```
ssh -t anvil "export V=hello; export W=world; bash"
```

followed by:

```
jla@anvil$ echo $V $W
hello world
```

Answer (score 3):

It is worth to note that `ssh -t`  can actually be used to connect to one host via another host.

So for example if you want to execute a command on *anvil*, but *anvil* is only accessible from host *gateway* (by firewall etc.), you can do like this:

```
ssh gateway -t 'ssh anvil -t "export V=hello; export W=world;bash -l";'
```

Exiting the *anvil*, will also log you out of *gateway* (if you want to stay on *gatway* after leaving anvil than just add another `bash -l` before closing the command.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to execute this beast (also gives me a colored shell):

`ssh host -t "echo 'rm /tmp/initfile; source ~/.bashrc; cd foo/; git status' > /tmp/initfile; bash --init-file /tmp/initfile"`