# Interactive c# System.Process not Echoing input

Tags: c#, linux, shell, ssh, mono

Given the following code running in Mono on Linux, I can successfully run ssh from C# and get a shell prompt on a remote box. I can type commands and get output. However I can't figure out how to get what I type into that shell to echo back. When I type `ls` and hit enter you don't see the `ls` or the newline from hitting the enter key, you only see it's output. I've verified ssh is assigning a tty. The destination shell is bash in interactive mode so readline is enabled there. The problem has to be in how C# is wiring up the STDIN and STDOUT up to the `Console`. Google is no help so I'm hoping someone on here can help.

```
var process_info = new ProcessStartInfo("/usr/bin/ssh");
process_info.Arguments =  "-ttt hostname";
Console.Out.WriteLine("Arguments: [" + process_info.Arguments + "]");
process_info.CreateNoWindow = true;
process_info.UseShellExecute = true;
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = process_info;
try {
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    exitCode = process.ExitCode;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    exitCode = this.ExitCode == 0 ? 255 : exitCode;
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
Console.Out.WriteLine("ExitCode: " + exitCode);
```

Comment: Works fine here, using  OpenSSH_6.0p1 on debian stable, with mono 3.10. What are your versions?

Comment: mono 3.10 OpenSSH on Ubuntu 14.06. You get the commands echoed back just fine?

Comment: Yes, see [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kAivA.png). I think you meant that, right? (Some parts censored ;))

Comment: Hrmmm interesting I wonder what is different about your environment from mine? Which .Net Framework are you using? I'm stuck on 4 for reasons we are correcting soon. Maybe it got fixed in 4.5?

Comment: Oh this *is* the effective sorce of the exe. The code compiles and executes (once the System.IO. line is removed) just fine on all the framework. Echoing is exactly the term that describes the expected bahavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're trying to do:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace Echo
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Read(StreamReader reader)
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    int current;
                    while ((current = reader.Read()) >= 0)
                        Console.Write((char)current);
                }
            }).Start();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"/usr/bin/ssh");
            startInfo.Arguments = "-ttty localhost";
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(15000); //time to login
            Read(process.StandardOutput);
            Read(process.StandardError);
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("echoing your input now");
            while (!process.HasExited)
                try { process.StandardInput.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine()); }
                catch {}
            Console.WriteLine(process.ExitCode.ToString());    
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1

You need to redirect the StandardInput in order to echo it, but then the cmd in windows will elaborate it line by line (even if you use Console.ReadKey() => process.StandardInput.Write), so you can't have shell support while typing (look at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed) if you want to dig in).
But mono with linux ssh behaves differently from windows cmd, so the following could be acceptable maybe:
commands are echoed and even the tab while typing a dir is managed (look at my screenshot below)! Finally please notice that the tty is correctly set.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Echo
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Process process;
        private static void Read(StreamReader reader)
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (!process.HasExited)
                {
                    int current;
                    while ((current = reader.Read()) >= 0)
                        Console.Write((char)current);
                }
            }).Start();

       }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"/usr/bin/ssh");
            startInfo.Arguments = "-ttty localhost";
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(15000); //time to login
            Read(process.StandardOutput);
            Read(process.StandardError);
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo echoing your input now");
            //Console.ReadLine();
            string theLine = "\n";
            while (!process.HasExited)
                try {
                    ConsoleKeyInfo kinfo =  Console.ReadKey(true);
                   char theKey = kinfo.KeyChar;
                    theLine += theKey;
                    process.StandardInput.Write(theKey) ;
                    process.StandardInput.Flush();
                    if (theKey.Equals('\n'))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(theLine);
                        theLine = "\n";
                    }

                }
                catch { }
            Console.WriteLine(process.ExitCode.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

[image: first example of using tab while typing a dir]
[image: check tty]
[image: example of echoing the ssh commmands]

EDIT 2

If you want to also manage the terminal escape sequences for the UpArrow/DownArrow, here is the code (tested on my Ubuntu terminal)

```
            string theLine = "\n";
            string theEsc = ((char)27).ToString();
            while (!process.HasExited)
                try {
                    //byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
                    ConsoleKeyInfo kinfo =  Console.ReadKey(true);
                    char theKey = kinfo.KeyChar;
                    theLine += theKey;
                    switch (kinfo.Key)
        {

case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                            process.StandardInput.Write(theEsc+"[B");
 break;
case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                            process.StandardInput.Write(theEsc+"[A");
 break;
default:
                            process.StandardInput.Write(theKey);
 break;
        }
                    process.StandardInput.Flush();
                    if (theKey.Equals('\n'))
                    {
                        Console.Write(theLine);
                        theLine = "\n";

                    }

                }
```

EDIT 3

Just a follow up to my comments with a suggested command to restore echo (reference [here](https://superuser.com/questions/858743/how-do-i-restore-input-echoing-in-the-terminal)).
This is the change to the code:

```
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("stty -a");
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("stty echo"); // or "reset" insted of "stty echo"
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo echoing your input now");
```

Back to your original code (since you're not redirecting the standard input), you could do something like the following

```
process_info.Arguments =  "-ttt hostname 'stty echo; '$SHELL' -i'"; // or reset insted of stty echo
```

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9302005/4569980) too.

**In conclusion** the *source* you're showing - and more specifically c# System.Process - is **not** supposed to *echo* anything (unless one intentionally redirects the standard I/O, as I've done here in my first example and in edit 1&2).
 *Echoing* is a behavior of the shell, in Linux as well as in Windows: that can be managed as shown in edit 3.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same problem and the analysis of user4569980 helped a lot.

The root cause of this behavior is that mono disables the echo functionality of the currently used tty.
See http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/ and https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/TermInfoDriver.cs#L204

I used the following workaround:

`// mono sets echo off for some reason, therefore interactive mode 
    // doesn't work as expected this enables this tty feature which
    // makes the interactive mode work as expected
    let private setEcho (b:bool) =
        // See https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/ConsoleDriver.cs#L289
        let t = System.Type.GetType("System.ConsoleDriver")
        if Env.isMono then
            let flags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static ||| System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
            if isNull t then
                eprintfn "Expected to find System.ConsoleDriver.SetEcho"
                false
            else
                let setEchoMethod = t.GetMethod("SetEcho", flags)
                if isNull setEchoMethod then
                    eprintfn "Expected to find System.ConsoleDriver.SetEcho"
                    false
                else
                    setEchoMethod.Invoke(null, [| b :> obj |]) :?> bool
        else false`

I'l leave it to the interested reader to convert this F# code to C#. It's basically simple reflection to `bool System.ConsoleDriver.SetEcho(bool enable)`.

Now use the following pseudo code:

`setEcho(true)
var p = startProcess ()
p.WaitForExit()
setEcho(false)`

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Just capture and duplicate STDIN.

```
process.Start();
StreamWriter processInputStream = process.StandardInput;
do {
    String inputText = Console.ReadLine():
    processInputStream.write(inputText);
while(!process.HasExited)
process.WaitForExit();
```

Now the SSH process is no longer capturing your input, so it should be displayed locally. If it doesn't, just add `Console.writeLine(inputText)` to the loop, and done.

If you want better control, consider reading and writing byte wise. Just beware that TAB and other control characters might not be that easy to handle.

If you really need these as well, use [ReadKey()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead and pass along whatever control characters you need. Remember to set `Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;` or you won't be able to send `CMD + c` at all without killing your application.

Oh, but sending control sequences (keys with CMD or ALT modifier) from .NET outside of Windows?
Uh... I think that one is actually of limits. That is part of `System.Window.Forms` and I have no clue how to replicate that behavior with pure C# outside of Windows.

As for the other, and probably much easier option:
Just don't invoke the naked ssh executable. Open a shell instead and run SSH inside of that thing. `/usr/bin/bash` and `"-c 'ssh -ttt hostname'"`. Your problem is TTY emulation, so just let the shell handle that for you. `Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;` still applies though, at least if you want to be able to pass through Ctrl+C as a command sequence.

Comment: Unfortunately if I intercept STDIN then it causes a problem on the other end where ssh won't assign a pseudo TTY and neither will bash thus disabling interactive readline support.