# ssh to Ubuntu Server, run some commands, and then leave myself the default prompt?

Tags: shell, ssh, ubuntu-server, startupscript

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9302005/248616), we can SSH remote to Ubuntu Server instance, and run command, and open a prompt

```
ssh -t host 'cmd1; cmd2; sh -i'
```

Though the shell prompt I get on my Ubuntu Server is not the default one i.e. as I try to run `~ ./bashrc`, I get the error as below snapshot.

So my need is

```
ssh -t host 'cmd1; cmd2; OPEN_DEFAULT_PROMPT'
```

where `OPEN_DEFAULT_PROMPT` will open default Ubuntu Server shell prompt right after `cmd1; cmd2`.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. This would be more at home on [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: then I suggest you post same thing to this question too http://stackoverflow.com/a/9302005/248616

Comment: If this questions is closed, then I will surprise to see why this one, http://stackoverflow.com/a/9302005/248616,  not closed and feel different with the current admin guys working here!

Answer (score 0):

Simply it is `bash` instead of `sh -i` i.e.

```
ssh -t host 'cmd1; cmd2; bash'
```