# Server asking terminal type prevents me from auto-running commands

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, server, terminal

I wish to ssh into a server in my department, `cd` to a directory automatically, and hopefully be able to auto-run other commands if I want. I have tried several ways that have worked for lots of people on stack-overflow, but they did not work for me.

I have tried the methods from the following threads:

- [Can I ssh somewhere, run some commands, and then leave myself a prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301917/can-i-ssh-somewhere-run-some-commands-and-then-leave-myself-a-prompt)
- [Run ssh and immediately execute command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522647/run-ssh-and-immediately-execute-command)

In particular, I have tried:

#### 1. ssh one-liner

```
ssh -t user@domain.com 'cd /some/path; bash -l'
```

and

#### 2. using the `expect` script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh $argv
send "cd /some/path\n"
interact
```

Both codes look fine, and have worked for people in the threads. However, they did not work for me.

The problem, I expect, lies in the fact that the department server asks me automatically about my terminal type as I login, preventing my auto-commands to be run properly.

```
$ ssh -t user@domain.com 'cd /some/path; bash -l'
Terminal type? [xterm-256color]
```

After hitting , it takes me into the home directory as if I haven't `cd` yet.
The second way gives a similar result.

How can I get over this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you're already using `expect`, you can just accept the xterm-256color terminal and `cd` to /some/path afterwards :-)

Comment: That worked for me! I fixed it by adding another `send "\n"` to auto-choose the terminal type!