# SSH : how to assign specifics directories to each user?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

No, it is not a duplicate of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626533/how-can-i-ssh-directly-to-a-particular-directory/626670), because I want to assign one directory to one (or more) user, when they log in throught SSH.

For example, according to user's loggin :

- `userFoo` => I want him to arrive `/somewhere/here/` after SSH login
- `userBar` => I want him to arrive `/somewhere/here/` after SSH login
- `userOof` => I want him to arrive `/anywhere/` after SSH login
- And so on.

How can I do that ?
(They are connection with PuTTY and I can't force them to connect with additionnal [data](https://superuser.com/questions/290544/set-current-working-directory-on-ssh) like `ssh -t user@server 'cd /home/some/dir ; exec "$SHELL"'`

Comment: Any reason not to just make that the user's home directory? That's where login shells typically spawn.

Comment: Keep in mind that chrooting is not as easy as you might think. Imagine the user going to `/somewhere/here/var/log/` instead of `/var/log/`, etc..

Comment: What is this question doing on StackOverflow (and getting upvotes)? It's mere offtopic.

Comment: @JeremyRoman : well, that's what I wanted ;) but I didnt think about "home directory"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the home directories of your users, as that's the place where they land after connecting.

The second to last entry in /etc/passwd holds this information, and can be edited for example from

```
userFoo:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/userFoo:/bin/bash
```

to

```
userFoo:x:1000:1000:,,,:/somewhere/here:/bin/bash
```

Comment: The user is still able to `cd /home/userFoo` to get back to his home dir. I don't get the OP's point :-S

Comment: The OP didn't state he needs a chrooted environment. Sometimes it's just for convenience. "Connect to theserver.com and edit index.html" or "Connect and type _touch tmp/restart.txt_" is straight forward, no need to instruct someone to change to /my/fancy/path/where/you/propably/type/a/wrong/letter where someone could get "lost" and doesn't know how to recover.

Comment: @DanFromGermany There's no indication that the OP wants to confine users to the desired directory, just to make that the default on login. The physical directory `/home/userFoo` could simply be deleted if necessary, because `/somewhere/here` is now the user's real home directory. Permissions for `userFoo` can also be adjusted to prevent him from accessing other directories.

Comment: We have to agree the OP is not clear about the purpose. 1) There's no need to grant someone access to SSH not able to move between directories on unix.  2) If the origin home gets deleted, and the home moved to /somewhere/here.. what's the benefit of that?

Comment: As @kwood said : `Sometimes it's just for convenience.` => It is my purpose. It's also a gain of time, for non-experimented users.
@kwood : Works perfectly as expected, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you log in a remote machine via SSH, it starts a shell, in most cases it's *bash*. It has a script, which executes every time it starts, can be found at *~/.bashrc*. You may edit them, append a *cd /somewhere* to them.

Anyway, it's probably not a good idea, it's better to link appropiate folders to the users:

```
ln -s /somewhere/here ~/userFoo/comehere
ln -s /somewhere/here ~/user/comehere
ln -s /anywhere ~/userOof/comehere
```

So, you may just tell the users "please perform a *cd comehere* after you log in", it will drop them to the specified folders.