# How to set default directory for when I open a new gnome-terminal with zsh?

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, gnome-terminal

When I open a new gnome terminal it loads `zsh` and puts me in my home directory (`~`). If I `cd` around and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> it opens a new tab in the same directory as my last tab. I like this behaviour, but instead of *starting* in my home dir, I want to start in some other dir. How can I do this?

I can't put a `cd` command in `~/.zshrc` because that will run when I open a new tab, and I can't put it in `~/.zprofile` because that just doesn't run when I open a new terminal. So how do I do it?

Comment: "I can't put it in ~/.zprofile because that just doesn't run when I open a new terminal." That's because you're not running `zsh` as a login shell.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Just checked my /etc/passwd file; it's set to /bin/zsh. Don't "login" terminals run when you SSH into a system but not when you open a new terminal window?

Comment: `~/.zlogin` perhaps?

Comment: @Mark No, whether to use login shells is entirely up to you. It depends on what command is being run by your terminal emulator upon creating a new session. `zsh` alone runs an interactive, non-login shell; `zsh -l` runs an interactive, login shell. This can usually be customized in your terminal emulator profile/settings/preferences. It won't help for your particular use case (which I believe need some special interaction with the terminal emulator — for instance on OS X with iTerm2 I can solve this problem with a special profile, or AppleScript), but it's still one good thing to know.

Comment: I just found [the option](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QQHax.png) to run zsh as a login shell, but it does this both when I open a new window and when I open a new tab.

Comment: @DonBottstein According to [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71258/45556) `.zprofile` runs before `.zshrc` and `.zlogin` runs after, but it's subject to the same problem.

Comment: @Mark Yeah, that's why I said "it won't help for your particular use case". This is not something you can do on the shell level; it really depends on your terminal emulator's features, and I can't comment on that because my terminal emulator is iTerm2 on OS X. (By the way, could you please mention me? I wouldn't see your comments if I didn't come back.)

Comment: @mpen : You did not specify how you start the gnome teminal, but in any case, you can configure gnome to use a certain command for starting the shell. Using this, you could for instance specify something like `STARTDIR=/foo/bar zsh`, and inside .zshrc, **if** STARTDIR is set, do the `cd $STARTDIR` and then unset the variable (so that the cd does not happen again, when you open a subshell subsequently).

Comment: @user1934428 Good point.. I could edit my taskbar icon to add some flags. I do all my work over ssh now though, so this sol'n worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/54242698/65387