# Conemu: Task to open ssh send password and a command

Tags: ssh, conemu

I am trying to launch ssh  to open a server, send my password and change the default directory

```
ssh -cur_console name@192.168.100.1
```

I know that this is probably simple but I can't seem to find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bare switch `-cur_console` has no sense. You may omit it.

Password authentication? Private/public key authentication is far better and secure. So try keys method and [ssh-agent](http://conemu.github.io/en/SshAgent.html) may be.

As about directory, there is an easy [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626574/1405560).

So, your question do not relate to ConEmu at all.

Comment: Im sorry, I think that my question was unclear. I am able to log in as normal. I am trying to create a task so then I run the cmd or use the hot key it will either open in current console or new console. I read the help file but am un clear on the cmd cur_console/new_console and the switches if I were to have a -new_console what would I use to open ssh username@192.168.1.1 then wait for load, send password, then send initial cmd of cd/ ...

Comment: Tasks are always opened in new tabs or splits.

Comment: If you need to execute some command frequently - use aliases, batch, or `print` GuiMacro files. Tasks were not intended do that.