# How to delete all files except the N newest files?

Tags: bash

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626533/how-can-i-ssh-directly-to-a-particular-directory) command allows me to login to a server, to a specific directory from my pc 
`ssh -t xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "cd /directory_wanted ; bash"`

**How can I then do this operation in that directory.** I want to be able to basically delete all files except the N most newest.
`find ./tmp/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname *.tgz | sort -n | head -n -10 | xargs rm -f`

Comment: You can replace `bash` in your first command with `find...` pipeline in second...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command,

```
ssh -t xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "cd /directory_wanted; ls -t *.tgz  | tail -n
+11 | xargs rm -f; bash"
```

In side quotes, we can add what ever the operations to be performed in remote machine. But every command should be terminated with semicolon (;)

Note: Included the same command suggested by silentMonk. It is simple and it is working. But verify it once before performing the operation.

Answer (score 7):

This command should work:

`ls -t *.tgz  | tail -n +11 | xargs rm -f`

**Warning**: Before doing `rm -f`, confirm that the files being listed by `ls -t *.tgz  | tail -n +11` are as expected.

**How it works:**

> `ls` lists the contents of the directory.`-t` flag sorts by
>   **modification time** (newest first). See the man page of [ls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html)
>
> `tail -n +11` outputs starting from line 11. Please refer the man page of
>   [tail](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) for more
>   detials.

If the system is a Mac OS X then you can delete based on **creation time** too. Use `ls` with `-Ut` flag. This will sort the contents based on the creation time.