# cleanup all files except the n most recent files (and failsafe when no files are present)

Tags: bash, find

If I have a process that creates output jpg files. I have a cleanup script where I want to clean all files except the 100 last files. I used this command:

```
find -H /tmp -name \*.jpg | xargs ls -rt | head -n -100 | xargs rm -f
```

This works fine, except when not a single jpg file is present, in that case the find command will produc no output; so `ls -rt` will start listing ALL files in /tmp and start removing random files that don't match the `*.jpg` patter. I use a workaround like this:

```
JPG_FILES=$(find -H /tmp -name \*.jpg)
if [ -n "$JPG_FILES" ]
then
    echo $JPG_FILES | xargs ls -rt | head -n -100 | xargs rm -f
fi
```

which works fine, but I think there might be a better workaround, or just a better way to do this kind of cleanup?

PS: I know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474635/how-to-delete-all-files-except-the-n-newest-files), but that gives me the bug where random old files are removed that are not jpgs.

Comment: Use this [Charles Duffy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26765341/5291015) and modify the statement to `(( ++count > 100 ))` and add `-name "*.jpg"` to the `find` command; to suit your requirement

Comment: You could evaluate the result of the find and check if its empty and only continue if its not. Something like this [ ! -z `find -name 'test'` ] &&  echo found 
where you exchange && for the ls command etc. (You will need backticks around the find command)

Comment: @telina you could at least have read my question to the end...

Comment: I mean I only tried to help. Maybe I didn't understand what you want then. I thought it would be a nice way to put it in one line.